# How to delete PDF pages based on keywords in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, acrobat

Each day I am working with a PDF document that is about 100 pages, with most pages that just read "No items to display". I normally use the "Organize Pages" feature in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC to manually delete those pages. Is there a JavaScript code I can run that will delete the pages that read "No items to display"? Or at least if a page has the word "display" it will be deleted?

I am using Adobe Acrobat Pro DC Version 21.0

Answer (score 0):

You will need the Acrobat JavaScript documentation for the exact syntax.

What you can do is parse the document with the `getNthWord()` method. You will then compare the fragments, and see if you can assemble your text; to verify that they really do match together, you will compare their coordinates. If the condition is fulfilled, create a table (aka array) with the page numbers to be deleted.

When you have gone through all pages, loop through that array (from high numbers to low) and delete the according pages.